# Selecting DropDown from list, the option has <Space>

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

```
public static WebElement residentialStatus(String name) {
    element = LoginPage.driver.findElement(By.xpath("PATH"));
    Select oSelect = new Select(element);
    oSelect.selectByVisibleText(name);
    System.out.println("Residential Status: " + name);
    return element;
}
```

the HTML is:

```
<select name="residentialStatus">
<option value="">--Please Select--</option>
<option value="B">Boarding</option>
<option value="O">Home Owner</option>
<option value="P">Living with Relative</option>
<option value="R">Renting</option>
```

In the above code, I am trying to select a Dropdown, 
When I am selecting 'Home Owner' it fails (possible because there is a Space), when I choose 'Boarding' or 'Renting' then it works fine. 
I am unable to understand where I am going wrong.
(Feeding Data from Excel, so I can't change it to 'selectByArray as all other dropdowns are working fine from the same excel)

Comment: How does 'Home Owner' looks like when taken from excel? any difference in spaces? in upper or lower case letters? Is it working with 'Living with Relative'?

Comment: in excel -> Home Owner, it's exactly how it is in the HTML. Not working for 'Living with Relative' also

Comment: Print the 'name' variable just to check what it is picking from the excel. If it is picking 'Home Owner' correctly then we need to investigate further.

Comment: Alok - I am new to coding & I consider your response was bang-on. I was able to resolve it. I printed to see what was coming from Excel & there was a prefix space, removed it & it worked. Also I changed the excel cell format to 'Text' from General.

Comment: Share the code with which you are taking values from Excel. I tried above select options , it did select Home Owner and other values with spaces also. There must be some minor fault in Datatype of cell in Excel and how you are taking it in your code. Hence do share that code.